# Big double value Calculation yield 1e+ as Result - iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to Multiply two big double values as follows.

long  double lastKnownValue;

and for eg: when i multiply two values like
1000 x 1000,i am expecting result as 1000000.
But it gives Result as 1e+06.

How can make the result as 1000000?;
for small numbers it works perfect.

[image]

Comment: 1e+06 is 1,000,000. how/where are you getting this output?

Comment: am using lastKnownValue *= currentValue; simple multiplication formula. and when i  NSLog(@"%Lg",lastKnownValue); it gives the above output.

Comment: pls show how you are doing it!

Comment: pls check my question.

Comment: You are the one who is saying `@"%Lg"`. Did you read the documentation? "64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in the style of %e if the exponent is less than –4 or greater than or equal to the precision, in the style of %f otherwise." So it is printing in the style of %e, exponential notation. It is doing exactly what you asked it to do. You have nothing to complain of.

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image, but include it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

> `long double`

use

```
unsigned long long
```

eg: `

> unsigned long long lastKnownValue;
>
> unsigned long long currentValue = [mainLabel.text longLongValue];
>
> NSLog(@"%llu",lastKnownValue);
>       //Set the new value to the main label
>       mainLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu",lastKnownValue];

Answer (score 0):

The `%g` and `%lg` format strings request scientific notation for large numbers, which is what you are getting. Try using `%Lf` (Are you sure it's an upper case "L" for long double? I thought it would be a lower-case L.) And if you don't want any digits after the decimal separator, use `%.0Lf` (Actually, I'm not sure of the order of the characters for specifying the number of decimal digits in a long double. It might be `%L.0f`, but I *think* the first version is correct.)